# Nodejs Express + Nuxt - Session Cookies

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am using an Express App for the backend and VueJs with Nuxt (Server Side Rendering). My problem is that the cookies are not getting saved when the session is getting refreshed.

Server:

```
const express = require('express')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const { loadNuxt } = require('nuxt')

const app = express()

app.use(cookieParser())

// Middleware
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  // ...
  
  if (sessionExpired && refreshTokenIsValid) {
    // Generate new session
    // ...
    res.cookie('sessionToken', token, { maxAge: 86400000, path: '/' })
    res.cookie('sessionId', id, { maxAge: 86400000, path: '/' })
    res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, { maxAge: 86400000, path: '/' })

    return next()
  }
})

...
```

Login route

```
router.get('/login', async (req, res, next) => {
  // ...
  res.cookie('sessionToken', token, { maxAge: 86400000, path: '/' })
  res.cookie('sessionId', id, { maxAge: 86400000, path: '/' })
  res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, { maxAge: 86400000, path: '/' })

  res.status(200).redirect('/')
})
```

Client:

```
async asyncData({ $axios }) {
   const data = await $axios.get('/something')
},
methods: {
  async someMethod() {
    let data = await this.$axios.$get('/something')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cookies are not getting saved when sending a request from asyncData().
I solved the problem by using an axios helper.
Solution source: [proxy cookies](https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/333)

```
// plugins/ssr-cookie-proxy.js
import { parse as parseCookie } from 'cookie';

function parseSetCookies(cookies) {
  return cookies
    .map(cookie => cookie.split(';')[0])
    .reduce((obj, cookie) => ({
      ...obj,
      ...parseCookie(cookie),
    }), {});
}

function serializeCookies(cookies) {
  return Object
    .entries(cookies)
    .map(([name, value]) => `${name}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`)
    .join('; ');
}

function mergeSetCookies(oldCookies, newCookies) {
  const cookies = new Map();

  function add(setCookie) {
    const cookie = setCookie.split(';')[0];
    const name = Object.keys(parseCookie(cookie))[0];

    cookies.set(name, cookie);
  }

  oldCookies.forEach(add);
  newCookies.forEach(add);

  return [...cookies.values()];
}

export default function ({ $axios, res }) {
  $axios.onResponse((response) => {
    const setCookies = response.headers['set-cookie'];

    if (setCookies) {
      // Combine the cookies set on axios with the new cookies and serialize them
      const cookie = serializeCookies({
        ...parseCookie($axios.defaults.headers.common.cookie),
        ...parseSetCookies(setCookies),
      });

      $axios.defaults.headers.common.cookie = cookie; // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign

      // If the res already has a Set-Cookie header it should be merged
      if (res.getHeader('Set-Cookie')) {
        const newCookies = mergeSetCookies(
          res.getHeader('Set-Cookie'),
          setCookies,
        );

        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', newCookies);
      } else {
        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', setCookies);
      }
    }
  });
}
```